# Convert Mongodb Date to R Date Object

Tags: r, mongodb, date

I have successfully pulled in some data from Mongodb. Although my data is in a data frame, my example here is just a vector. I have a vector of dates but I can't figure out how to convert them into a valid date in R.

```
example <- c(123073732713600000,
             123073706793600000,
             123073680873600000,
             123073654953600000,
             123073629033600000,
             123073603113600000
            )
```

I want to convert the above integers into the following dates. The data set I have also returns the date as a date string, but I've been told the "date" field is more reliable than the date string field.

I believe these are the correct answers, but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
"Fri Feb 20 15:34:59 EST 2015"
"Fri Feb 20 15:29:59 EST 2015"
"Fri Feb 20 15:24:59 EST 2015"
"Fri Feb 20 15:19:59 EST 2015"
"Fri Feb 20 15:14:59 EST 2015"
"Fri Feb 20 15:09:59 EST 2015"
```

If anyone can give me code to convert the example vector into a vector of valid R dates that match the above date times, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure,

```
time <- as.POSIXct(example/100000000, origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:01")
> time
[1] "2008-12-31 16:28:48 CET" "2008-12-31 16:24:28 CET" "2008-12-31 16:20:09 CET" "2008-12-31 16:15:50 CET" "2008-12-31 16:11:31 CET" "2008-12-31 16:07:12 CET"
```

Comment: That's closer. I confess, I never got past as.POSIXct(example, origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:01"), but this is closer, but I know the date fields are from 2015. According to Mongodb's documentation, they use an origin of 1970-01-01, so I don't understand what I'm getting.

Comment: as.POSIXct(example/86400000, origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:01")

Comment: The above code is very close to being "right" but I don't understand why. My seconds are a fraction off, but not enough to really matter. I basically got this by experimentation. Not sure, yet, if it works well for all of the data or not.

Comment: I'm also hoping someone has an explanation, because I'm not really convinced this is "the answer".